# Acessar uma variável de uma função

Tags: c, funções, variáveis, escopo-de-variáveis

Em C, posso utilizar uma variável fora do escopo onde ela foi declarada?

Sei que o melhor a ser feito é declara-la fora de qualquer função, pois assim ela se tornará global. Mas quero saber como opera-la caso a variável esteja dentro de uma função específica.

Exemplo da dúvida: no código abaixo, como eu chamaria a variável `quantidadePar`, que esta declarada dentro da função `parImpar()`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int parImpar(int *a){
    int quantidadePar;

    if(*a%2 == 0){
        quantidadePar++;
        return 1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}

int main(){
   int num;

   scanf("%d", &num);

   parImpar(&num);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: "posso utilizar uma variável fora do escopo onde ela foi declarada?" **Não**. Se precisa dela em outro lugar, declare em um escopo mais externo.

Comment: "Sei que o melhor a ser feito é declara-la fora de qualquer função, pois assim ela se tornará global. " Esta afirmação vem de onde exatamente?

Comment: A resposta resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitá-la? Veja o [tour] se não souber como faz. Isso ajudaria muito indicar que a solução foi útil para você. Também pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 3):

> Em C, posso utilizar uma variável fora do escopo onde ela foi declarada?

Não, a variável só existe no escopo que foi declarada.

> Sei que o melhor a ser feito é declará-la fora de qualquer função, pois assim ela se tornará global. Mas quero saber como operá-la caso a variável esteja dentro de uma função específica.

Não, isto é o pior que pode fazer, não o melhor. E sim, ela se tornará global, este é o problema. Não que não possa fazer nunca, mas precisa saber usar muito bem, deveria ser algo bem avançado para se fazer e não como solução paliativa porque não domina o mecanismo básico. Está no caminho certo.

> Exemplo da dúvida: no código abaixo, como eu chamaria a variável 'quantidadePar', que esta declarada dentro da função 'parImpar'?

Não chamaria, na verdade chamar aí é um termo equivocado, funções são chamadas, variáveis não são. Depende do que quer, mas em essência este código está todo errado.

Primeiro, esta função tem duas responsabilidades, e isto costuma ser errado, mas se quiser insistir assim teria que comunicar a variável entre as funções (vou desconsiderar gambiarras só para funcionar). Como em C só pode retornar um único valor não costumamos fazer mecanismos que simulem retorno múltiplo, teria que passar a variável por referência, algo assim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int parOuImpar(int valor, int *quantidade) {
    if (valor % 2 == 0) {
        (*quantidade)++;
        return 1;
    } else return 0;
}

int main(){
   int num;
   scanf("%d", &num);
   int quantidade = 0;
   if (parOuImpar(num, &quantidade)) printf("O dado é par e isto ocorreu %d vezes", quantidade);
   else  printf("O dado é impar");
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ZCiETu). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/@maniero/MantainState). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Function/MantainState.c).

Percebeu? A variável global parece mais fácil e para um exercício é, mas quando for fazer uma aplicação de verdade começa complicar ter este tipo de coisa, então o correto é comunicar essa variável por parâmetro mesmo, passando ela por referência. Tem outros mecanismos, mas os bons são mais complexos ainda. Se não faz ideia do que seja isto provavelmente está fazendo algo mais avançado do que conhece nesse momento.

A solução mais correta seria ter uma função que só faça uma das duas coisas. E nem é difícil fazer isto, se você não precisar saber diretamente se é par ou não fica fácil, porque basta passar o valor e quantidade de forma simples (sem ponteiro), e aí só retorna o valor da nova quantidade que será incrementado de acordo com a condição se é par. Aí no retorno você compara o valor que passou com o valor retornado, se for diferente é porque é par. O nome da função deveria mudar para indicar bem o que ela faz agora. Consegue fazer isto? Atende sua necessidade?